# Data in table not displaying the way I want it to

Tags: php, html-table

I have a spinner and what happens is that whatever number is in the spinner, when the form is submitted, it should display the word "quest" as many times as the number in the spinner.. E.g if number in spinner is 3, then it will display "quest" 3 times in the table.

The problem is displaying it in the table.

At the moment with my current code it is displaying it like this:

```
quest
quest
quest

Question Id, Option Type, Duration .... These are table headings
```

It is displaying the words quest outside the table

Instead I want the word "quest" to be displayed in the Question Id column like this:

```
Question Id, Option Type, Duration...

quest
quest
quest
```

How can I get it to display it like the example above?

```
Below is code

 <table border=1 id="qandatbl" align="center">
    <tr>
    <th class="col1">Question No</th>
    <th class="col2">Option Type</th>
    <th class="col1">Duration</th>
    <th class="col2">Weight(%)</th>
    <th class="col1">Answer</th>
    <th class="col2">Video</th>
    <th class="col1">Audio</th>
    <th class="col2">Image</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $spinnerCount = $_POST['txtQuestion'];
if($spinnerCount > 0) {
   for($i = 1; $i <= $spinnerCount; $i++) {
     echo "<tr>quest";
   }
}
?>
    <td class='qid'></td>
    <td class="options"></td>
    <td class="duration"></td>
    <td class="weight"></td>
    <td class="answer"></td>
    <td class="video"></td>
    <td class="audio"></td>
    <td class="image"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I did try echo `"<td class='qid'></td>";` but this completely failed as well

Comment: I just took a quick look but it looks like you never end your tr tag?

Comment: And in `echo "<tr>quest";` should be a `<td>` after `<tr>`

Comment: </tr> tag is at the bottom after all <td>'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to do? Display "quest" in the first column?

```
<table border=1 id="qandatbl" align="center">


   <tr>
    <th class="col1">Question No</th>
    <th class="col2">Option Type</th>
    <th class="col1">Duration</th>
    <th class="col2">Weight(%)</th>
    <th class="col1">Answer</th>
    <th class="col2">Video</th>
    <th class="col1">Audio</th>
    <th class="col2">Image</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $spinnerCount = $_POST['txtQuestion'];
if($spinnerCount > 0) {
   for($i = 1; $i <= $spinnerCount; $i++) { ?>
     <tr>

    <td class='qid'>quest</td>
    <td class="options"></td>
    <td class="duration"></td>
    <td class="weight"></td>
    <td class="answer"></td>
    <td class="video"></td>
    <td class="audio"></td>
    <td class="image"></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
}
?></table>
```

?>

Comment: Yeah thats has worked brillaintly, I don't kno why I dint think of displaying whole table rather than just echo "qid" row. thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table border=1 id="qandatbl" align="center">
<tr>
  <th class="col1">Question No</th>
  <th class="col2">Option Type</th>
  <th class="col1">Duration</th>
  <th class="col2">Weight(%)</th>
  <th class="col1">Answer</th>
  <th class="col2">Video</th>
  <th class="col1">Audio</th>
  <th class="col2">Image</th>
</tr>
<?php
 $spinnerCount = $_POST['txtQuestion'];
  if($spinnerCount > 0) {
   for($i = 1; $i <= $spinnerCount; $i++) {
?>

  <tr>
   <td class='qid'><?php echo $quest; ?></td>
   <td class="options"></td>
   <td class="duration"></td>
   <td class="weight"></td>
   <td class="answer"></td>
   <td class="video"></td>
   <td class="audio"></td>
   <td class="image"></td>
</tr>
<?php
 } // For
} // If
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank u, that is same as the above answer and u r right as well as the answer above is also correct. thank u :)